# SAPUI5 table dynamic data loading from XML model

Tags: sapui5

I want to use SAPUI5 table to display many data sets (>100k rows) which come from a backend. In order to divide the data sets onto pages, I could set the navigation mode to paginator. But this only affects the client-side. The backend supports to define an offset and number of data sets which should be returned by URL parameter.

How is it possible to only load a specific number of data sets and load additional data sets if another page should be shown? It is not possible to use OData model. Only the XML model is applicable. Does SAPUI5 provide a builtin functionality for this? The paginator does not provide any events for navigation interaction.

Comment: Why isn´t it possible to use the `ODataModel`? It offers you all you need such as lazy loading. What´s on your backend side?

Comment: The backend is an old version of SAP MII (12.2) which only supports XML format. Only newer versions support OData protocol. No matter if it is supported or not, this would be no option.